# How to retrieve pseudo-element transform-style value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

**Situation:**

```
div.xy:hover {
  transform: all rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

**Question:**
I need to retrieve the *360* therewith I can display and change it. 
Need some help with the path that leads me to the 360.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I believe `document.getElementById('XYZ').style.WebkitTransform` will return `"rotate(360deg)"` in WebKit browsers. You can use `style.MozTransform` for Firefox 3.1+, `style.msTransform` for IE9+, `style.OTransform` for Opera.

Source: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html

To bind element with mouse events:

```
var e = document.getElementById('test') // Your div ID

e.onmouseover = function(){
    var degree = 360; // Rotation on :hover
    e.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.OTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
}
e.onmouseout = function(){
    var degree = 0; // Initial rotation
    e.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.OTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    e.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
}
```

It might be simpler with jQuery, but you've got to know your JavaScript roots!
​

Comment: It works, thanks, but only with the div, not with div:hover.
Any possibility to change the div:hover style?

Comment: I don't know a way to modify the element `:hover` style with `JavaScript`, but you could bind `.onmouseover` and `.onmouseout` events on the element. See my updated answer.

Comment: +1 for nice answer - Don't you know how to set `transform-origin` for all browser with Javascript as well, please...?

Comment: @Ωmega: I think you could do the same thing, using `element.style.webkitTransformOrigin = "50% 50%";` and `element.style.mozTransformOrigin = "50% 50%";`. Note that I didn't test it and I don't think you can do msTransformOrigin and OTransformOrigin for Opera & IE... Yet.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need jQuery but it might be what you are looking for....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".xy:hover").css("transform")


});
```

This return the value as a string. You probably should check if it returns `360deg` or the whole thing.
Drop the `div` for both jQuery and CSS. For jQuery is faster not to call it and in CSS it doesn't add specificity.

Comment: Thanks, but I know nothing about jQuery. Just started with basic Javascript and move forward to AJAX now. Is there no solution with simple Javascript?

Comment: I think remimbreton's answer is what you're looking for